# Defining full range of byte array values in hex in Java

Tags: java

I know of being able to define a byte array with hex values in Java like this:

```
byte[] options = { 0x01, 0x00, 0x2f, 0x00 };
```

However, would like to be able to define the byte value for the full range of hex like 0xff, 0xf2, etc. In golang, you can provide such values to the literal byte array definition, e.g.

```
// in golang
gd := []byte{0xff, 0xf2}
fmt.Printf("%v", gd) // prints out [255 242]
```

How to do the equivalent in Java? I'm a novice with working with bytes in Java, maybe I missed the proper way to handle byte values that are larger numbers or where unsigned values come into play.

In Java attempting to do what I did in golang, the IDE shows warning/error indicator, and at compile time, get failure message like "incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from int to byte". What's the proper way to define the byte value in such cases?

Comment: `byte[] options = { 0x01, 0x00, (byte)0x2f, 0x00 };`. Add a `(byte)` cast for all the values that offend, which will be all of them `>= 0x80`.

Comment: An alternative to actually coding the bytes is to create a `String` literal (or value) containing the hex or b64 encoding and decode it when convenient, often as a class `static` field depending on what you want to do. Below Java 9 you could use jaxb DatatypeConverter for hex; now you must write your own, but it's only a few lines once. For b64 Java 8 up has `java.util.Base64`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`byte` are signed in Java: you can use `Byte.toUnsignedInt(options[0])` to get the value:

```
jshell> byte[] options = { (byte)0xff, (byte) 0xf2};
options ==> byte[2] { -1, -14 }
```

You will have to cast value from `int` (0xFF = 255 (int)) to `byte` (-1).

If you want to print out the array, the values will be signed as shown above: you will have to convert the `byte[]` into `int[]` using `Byte.toUnsignedInt` for each index, then use `Arrays.toString` for a String display:

```
jshell> int[] uns = new int[options.length];
uns ==> int[2] { 0, 0 }

jshell> for (int i = 0; i < uns.length; ++i) {uns[i] = Byte.toUnsignedInt(options[i]);}

jshell> Arrays.toString(uns)
$9 ==> "[255, 242]"
```

**Note:** `jshell` is a repl that was added in Java at least since Java 11.